# Ember.js project directory structure

Tags: ember.js

Is there any good tutorial or Ember.js document describing directory structure for models / views / controllers, app.js and the way to reference those files in the index.html root file.

- File to create the "Ember.Application.create" ?
- order of inclusion (models.js, apps.js, controllers.js) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There still seems to be no clear convention, but currently many people seem to be using Yeoman and the official Ember generator https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember

While I appreciate the "open" nature of the Ember tutorials, one of the nice things about Rails is the convention of file placement. When we hire a new developer, we don't need to give an explanation about our directory structure... I hope Ember sets an official standard soon.

Answer (score 4):

[This tutorial by Dan Gebhardt](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/01/24/beginning-ember-js-on-rails-part-1/) was very helpful to me in setting up my project structure and figuring out how to include files.

Comment: +1. I really like this structure. In my opinion it is much better for mid-range to larger applications then the accepted answer, that will probably get messy quite quickly.

Answer (score 4):

The [ember-skeleton project](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton) has a reasonable example of project layout for rake pipeline. They do it something like this ([from the README](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton#app-structure)):

```
ember-skeleton
├── Assetfile - App build file
├── Gemfile - Package dependencies for rakep/rack
├── Gemfile.lock - Here be dragons: don't touch, always include
├── app - App specific code
│   ├── css - App CSS or SCSS (.scss)
│   ├── lib - App code, *modularized during build*
│   ├── modules - Module code, *already modularized*
│   ├── plugins - Plugins (e.g. jquery.jsonrpc.js)
│   │   └── loader.js - JS module loader
│   ├── static - Static files, never touched, copied over during build
│   ├── templates - Handlebars templates, *modularized during build*
│   ├── tests - QUnit application tests
│   └── vendor - Vendor code, *modularized during build*
├── assets - Built out asset files, minified in production
│   ├── app.css - Built out app CSS/SCSS
│   ├── app.js - Built out app JS
│   └── loader.js - Built out JS module loader
├── config.ru - Rack development web server configuration
├── index.html - The app entry point
├── tests - QUnit testing files
│   ├── index.html - The testing entry point
│   ├── qunit - Testing support files
│   └── run-tests.js - The PhantomJS QUnit test runner
└── tmp - Temporary build files used by rakep
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a layout that I am pretty happy with

app.js - this is the main application file and includes settings and the router

views.js - contains views used within the app, although I usually now split this out to homeView.js navigtaionView.js etc

dataModels.js - this is where I hold all my data model objects for the app

dataSources.js - I use this to load datamodels or arrays of datamodels from any api calls I make

accountController.js - controller class, in the attached sample I also have an emailMessagingController and an smsMessagingController

You can find my sample project here

https://github.com/bwship/neptunejs

and the coffeescript files for ember here

https://github.com/bwship/neptunejs/tree/master/public/coffeescripts

and finally the jad file for the layout and index showing how I add these here

https://github.com/bwship/neptunejs/tree/master/views

I do want to eventually start using the ember data style, but have put out a few solid apps using the dataSources and dataModels files.

Comment: I would say this is a good starting point for smaller apps. However, I think this tends to get messy quite quickly if you want to build larger apps and splitting up to seperate model/view/controller/template files then would be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I set it up on larger projects with app, controllers, models, routes, and views folder with separate files for each.  And then a templates folder with the handlebars templates.